# PIG : research in many files

Tags: apache-pig

I'm a newbie in PIG, and i have a problem. I don't know if it's possible.

Fist of all, i have a file with this :

> ?(A, B, C, D) :- File1(A), File2(B), File3(C), File4(A, B), File5 (A, C), File6(C, B), File7(A, D).

And I have to create a script in PIG, taking this file, and, for each entry, research into the File the parameter ...

For example, in this one, the script has to find in the File1, the parameter A, in File2 B, File3C ...

But I don't know how many file there is. They can only have 1 parameter or 2.

I can easy load theses files, and they have all 2 columns.

> For each File {
>
> > A = load 'FileX' using PigStorage (':') as (Col1:chararray, Col2:chararray);
> >
> > B = filter A by Col1 == X AND Col2== Y;
> >
> > STORE B INTO 'result' using PigStorage(' ');
>
> }

Is this type of code possible ?

In a second way, i wanted to regroup the files with the same parameters :
For File1, File5 and File7 via a group, or something ... To avoid the duplication of the same filtering.
I have done a lot of tests, but i didn't found anything useful.
Thank you :)

Comment: Is your first file also in hdfs?

Comment: Yes,It is in Hdfs too :)

Answer (score 0):

Is this type of code possible ?

No, Pig is just a data flow and there is no control flow.

> Pig Latin is a dataflow language. Unlike general-purpose programming
>   languages, it does not include control flow constructs such as if and
>   for. [ref](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001811/ch09.html).

You can embed your Pig script in python java or java-script script to enable flow controlling, see [here](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/cont.html#embed-python).

Comment: Thanks, I dont really understand how to incorporate a java script into a pig script, But i'll try !

Can i regroup all in the same script ? Or i have to creat 2 scripts ( I mean one un pig and the other one in java ?)

Comment: You will get only one java program, please check above link.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably have a combination of shell script and pig here.

Your pig script should look like

```
A = load '$inputfile' using PigStorage (':') as (Col1:chararray, Col2:chararray);
B = filter A by Col1 == X AND Col2== Y;
STORE B INTO 'result' using PigStorage(' ');
```

then you call this pig script from a shell

you can do a

```
for a in `hadoop fs cat <firstfile> | awk -F "," '{print $0}'`
do
pig -f script.pig -param inputfile=$a
done
```

Comment: But it won't work if there is only 1 parameter, Right ?

And i couldn't join sames parameters with this.